# Divisor summatory function for Odd and Even numbers

Tags: number-theory, divisor-counting-function

With Dirichlet's Divisor summatory function the mean divisor growth can be determined.

$$D(x)=\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^x d(x)= \log(x)+2 \gamma -1+ \mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

Where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant and $d(n)$ is the divisor function. Do there exist expressions where the Divisor summatory function is expressed in: $D(x=odd)$ and $D(x=even)$?

Background for question error growth "Wave Divisor Function":

[Error in Divisor Function Modelled With Waves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427431/650339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the question but if one wants the expressions for $d_{odd}(x)=\sum_{2k+1 \le x}d(2k+1)$ and $d_{even}$, one can easily get them from the recurrence:

$d_{even}(x)=2d_r(x/2)-d_r(x/4), d_{odd}(x)=d_r(x)-2d_r(x/2)+d_r(x/4)$ where $d_r(x)=xD(x)$ the usual divisor sum - these follow from the relation $d(4q)=2d(2q)-d(q)$ for any integer $q \ge 1$

In particular one gets that $D_{odd}=\frac{1}{4}\log x+\frac{1}{4}(2\gamma -1 + \log 4)+ O(1/\sqrt x)$ and $D_{even}=\frac{3}{4}\log x+\frac{3}{4}(2\gamma -1) -\frac{1}{4}\log 4+ O(1/\sqrt x)$

One can also apply Perron to get the principal terms - for the usual divisor sum it is the residue at $1$ of $\zeta^2(s)x^s/s$, while here one can immediately notice that $\zeta_{odd}(s)=(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s)$ so squaring $\zeta_{odd}(s)^2x^s=\zeta^2(s)x^s-2\zeta^2(s)(x/2)^s+\zeta^2(s)(x/4)^s$ from which the above follow easily too

Comment: Thank you!!! I do not understand all, but the expressions you gave help me further study! I will try to fit these expressions in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589203/follows-the-cosine-sum-of-divisors-an-arcsine-random-walk

Comment: Sorry, one question: is divisor 1 included for both: Dodd and for Deven?

Comment: yes - though the answer refers to the sum of divisors of odd numbers and the sum of divisors of even numbers ($d(2k), d(2k+1)$) not to the sum of the odd/even divisors of a number (those have different asymptotics)